# Javascript Regex: Exclude all other except one possibility

Tags: javascript, regex

I want few validations like (for my url):

cars : valid

cars/ : valid
(Any number of '/' after cars are valid)

cars- : invalid

cars* : invalid

carsp : invalid
(Any other character after cars except '/' is invalid)

**cars/new: valid

cars/old: valid
(Once we get '/' we can have anything).**

What should be regex for this: 
I tried with:
cars[/]*[^-]

Its not working.

Comment: How about this? `^cars\/?$`

Comment: Why this `[^-]` ? Why not simply `cars\/*$` ?

Comment: I think you should check on what is valid, and not on what is not, since I suppose there is a lot more invalid, than valid... As I understand, all that is allowed is `cars` followed by 0 or more slashes?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Though the title does not really state what you want.

Comment: To "exclude" something from matching a regexp, you simply do not put that pattern in the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^cars(\/.*)?$
```

`^...$` String should start with, and end with (Or simply, the string should only contain).

`cars` cars

`(...)?` and possibly

`\/.*` a forward slash followed by any character.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want "cars" followed by either

- nothing
- or anything starting by at least one /

So this would be

```
cars(\/.*)?
```

But the real problem here is determining what you really need. Some context might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *positive look-ahead assertion*:

```
/^cars(?=\/).*/
```

If there is a slash right after 'cars' word than it considers the rest part of the string